# how to get get_theme_mod value into array in wordpress?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, customization

I want to make an array by theme_mod value in wp theme customizer.

for example in this code:

```
$arr = array(com, net, org);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    echo "<div id='domain-$value'></div>";
}
```

I have an array like above with some tlds and want to set it dynamically by wp mcomstomizer.

I had a try by put "get_theme_mod( 'tlds' );" (like below) in array but no success and it put all the value in just one array key.

```
$arr = array(get_theme_mod( 'tlds' ););
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    echo "<div id='domain-$value'></div>";
}
```

How to put values into array and separate every array by comma,?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the soloution by [explode](http://php.net/explode). Thank You

```
$tlds = get_theme_mod( 'tlds' );
$arr = explode(', ', $tlds);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    echo "<div id='domain-$value' class='col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 otherdomains'></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`get_them_mods()` should return an array that you can loop over.

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mods

You can use `array_values()`

Example:

```
$arr = get_them_mods();
$temp = array_values($arr);
foreach ($temp as $value) {
    echo "<div id='domain-$value'></div>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code but it's Not worked and have no output.

Comment: can you put here your `get_theme_mod( 'tlds' )` output here ?